# Why does my {wrapfigure} cause the text to remain on one side of the page for several lines after the image ends?

Tags: alignment, wrapfigure, text, wrapfig

[image]

I'm trying to write notes for a microbiology class and I'd love to have the itemized list wrap around the image. What I don't understand however, is why the text below the image continues to act as if there was a figure on the right side of it?

```
    Lahko pa idejo Kochovih postulatov apliciramo tudi na molekularne metode. Ideja tega je, da obstojajo patogeni delci mikrobov ali markerji, ki so zadolženi za povzročanje bolezni in se nahajajo v več različnih vrstah. Preko novodobnih molekularnih metod lahko tako izoliramo izbran gen iz znanega patogenega mikroba in ga vnesemo v nepatogen sev iste vrste ter opazujemo spremembe v fenotipu mikroba. Takšen pristop je uporaben pri identifikaciji patogenih genov v človeku, bakterijah, glivah...
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image4.jpeg}
\end{wrapfigure}
Za razumevanje poteka okužbe je potrebno poznati nekaj ključnih pojmov in konceptov:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Razlika med \textbf{primarnim patogenom/oportunistom}, razlika med \textbf{patogenostjo/virulenco}.
    \item Kateri so dejavniki virulence.
    \item Razlika med \textbf{simptomatsko/asimptomatsko okužbo/kolonizacijo}.
    \item Razumevanje pojma \textbf{klicenoštvo}.
    \item Razumevanje Kochovih postulatov.
    \item Razlike v tipih pojavljanja endemično, sporadično, izbruh, epidemija, pandemija.
\end{itemize}
\subsection*{Patogenost in virulenca}
Patogenost je sposobnost mikroorganizma, da povzroča bolezen. Patogene mikroorganizme delimo na primarne patogene in oportunistične mikroorganizme. Virulenca pa je pojem, ki opisuje stopnjo patogenosti nekega mikroba. Razlike v virulenci obstajajo že med sevi iste vrste mikroorganizma, kjer lahko različni sevi povzročajo tudi različne bolezni. Poznati pa moramo tudi razliko med patogenom in komenzalom. Kot smo že omenili je patogen nek mikroorganizem, ki je sposoben povzročati bolezensko stanje. Komenzal pa je mikroorganizem, ki v gostiteljevem imunskem sistemu sproži zaščitne odzive, s katerimi se preprečuje kolonizacija patogenov.
```

Comment: please always show code as text not an image. wrapfig explicitly documents that you can not use lists in the wrapping text

Comment: you can use two minipage, one with a list and one with an image

Comment: Wrapfigure assumes every line of text takes up precisely \baselineskip.  You can usually fix it by using the optional "number of lines" argument.  OTOH, it is completely incompatible with \subsection,  I would use paracol instead.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document (caled Minimal Working Example: MWE) which begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` which reproduce your problem. A mention @DavidCarlisle, possible solution can be `\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize} ... 
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} 
                            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{...}
                            \end{minipage}
\end{center}`.